# Why is my cycling background not cycling through the photos array state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a cycling background that changes the background image through the background-image css property.
Basically I fetch 10 random images from unsplash api, and assign them to the `photos` array object.
Then I change the background image by changing the index in the photos array after a certain interval

I tried logging `ImageIndex` and all I get is `NaN` when I try to log it inside my CyclingBackground component.

I suspect that I might be having a synchronization problem here that I'm not aware of.

```
import { useState, useEffect, CSSProperties } from "react"
import "./CyclingBackground.css"
import { unsplashClient } from "@/config/global"
import { UnsplashImage } from "@/utils/types"

export default function CyclingBackground() {
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0)
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0.6)
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<UnsplashImage | UnsplashImage[]>([])
  const [backgroundImageUrl, setBackgroundImageUrl] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSplashImages = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await unsplashClient.photos.getRandom({ count: 10 })
        if (res && Array.isArray(res.response)) {
          setPhotos(res.response as UnsplashImage[])
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
    fetchSplashImages()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeIndex = () => {
      setImageIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % Object.values(photos).length)
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setOpacity(0)
      changeIndex()

      setOpacity(0.6)
    }, 8000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.values(photos).length > 0) {
      const imageUrl = photos[imageIndex as keyof typeof photos]?.urls?.full

      if (imageUrl) {
        setBackgroundImageUrl(imageUrl)
      }
    }
  }, [imageIndex, photos])

  let backgroundImageStyle: CSSProperties = {
    backgroundImage: backgroundImageUrl ? `url(${backgroundImageUrl})` : "",
    opacity: opacity,
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "repeat-y",
  }

  return <div className="cyclingBackground absolute" style={backgroundImageStyle}></div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `photos.length` on 1st render is 0 and `number % 0` is `NaN`. Since you always use the previous state when you calculate the new state, the result would always be `NaN`.

The interval's `useEffect` should be dependent on `photos`, and should skip starting the interval loop, if `photos.length` is 0:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!photos.length) return

  const changeIndex = () => {
    setImageIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % photos.length)
  }
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setOpacity(0)
    changeIndex()

    setOpacity(0.6)
  }, 8000)

  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [photos])
```

In addition `backgroundImageUrl` state is redundant, since it's derived from `photos` and `imageIndex`. Remove the 3rd use effect, and just compute it in the component's body. This would save you a render cycle:

```
const backgroundImageUrl = photos[imageIndex]
```

One last thing - according to your code, `photos` is an array, so you don't need to use `Object.values(photos)` (which returns a new array) to get the length `photos.length` is enough.

Full example:

```
export default function CyclingBackground() {
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0)
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0.6)
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState<UnsplashImage | UnsplashImage[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSplashImages = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await unsplashClient.photos.getRandom({ count: 10 })
        if (res && Array.isArray(res.response)) {
          setPhotos(res.response as UnsplashImage[])
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
    fetchSplashImages()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!photos.length) return
    
    const changeIndex = () => {
      setImageIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % photos.length)
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setOpacity(0)
      changeIndex()

      setOpacity(0.6)
    }, 8000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [photos])
  
  const backgroundImageUrl = photos[imageIndex]

  let backgroundImageStyle: CSSProperties = {
    backgroundImage: backgroundImageUrl ? `url(${backgroundImageUrl})` : "",
    opacity: opacity,
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "repeat-y",
  }

  return <div className="cyclingBackground absolute" style={backgroundImageStyle}></div>
}
```

Comment: perfectly worded! genius!